# Online/Offline events not firing in Service Worker on Chrome

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

This is the service worker for my app:

```
let isOnline = false;

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  console.log('SW: install');
  if (navigator.onLine) {
    console.log('SW: install - online');
  }
  if (!navigator.onLine) {
    console.log('SW: install - offline');
  }
  self.skipWaiting();
});

// Online event listener
self.addEventListener('online', function (event) {
  isOnline = true;
  console.log('SW: Online');
});

// Offline event listener
self.addEventListener('offline', function (event) {
  isOnline = false;
  console.log('SW: Offline');
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
  console.log('SW: flag', isOnline);
  if (self.navigator.onLine) {
    console.log('SW: Fetch Online');
  }
  if (!self.navigator.onLine) {
    console.log('SW: Fetch Offline');
  }
  // console.log('SW: fetch', event, event.request, event.request.body);
});
```

It's install/register (in the HTML), and the fetch handlers are all working. But the online/offline events don't seem even to be firing when I click the "offline" checkbox in the Application tab in Chrome Dev Tools.

This is my first service worker/PWA, so I'm pretty green at this, but I'm clearly missing something or doing something wrong. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: The [`online`, `offline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/online_event#browser_compatibility) events don't seem to be available on Chrome.